# How can i implement auto suggestion like browser search field (Not auto complete drop down)?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, python-3.x

I would like to implement auto suggestion feature just like browser search field works.

It don't want to select from the auto complete drop down list. The suggestion should be in the field it self and on clicking right arrow or tab the word/sentence should be completed in the field.

[image]

[image]

Can any body help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you alright with using libraries? Or would you want to do it with Vanilla JavaScript/Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick solution, I can recommend the following libraries. Both of the libraries below will meet your requirements of autocompleting the input by pressing tab.

Do take note that you will have to configure your server-side and front-end logic to pre-fetch/lazy-fetch the data that is to be supplied as the source for the autocomplete.

1) [Suggest](http://polarblau.github.io/suggest/) - 'enter' or 'tab' to accept the autocomplete suggestion.

2) [Typeaheard](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) - A more popular alternative. You can use tab to autocomplete too. However, this comes with a dropdown list, but you can do some DOM manipulation with JavaScript/Jquery and hide the dropdownlist.